# Comparing two joda DateTime instances

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a problem with the comparing two DateTime objects.

```
System.out.println(response.getCreationDate().toString()); // will return "2013-12-31T22:59:21.000+01:00", but...

assertThat(response.getCreationDate(), equalTo(new DateTime("2013-12-31T22:59:21+01:00"))); // will throw an assertation error with the following error

Expected: <2013-12-31T22:59:21.000+01:00>
 but: was <2013-12-31T22:59:21.000+01:00>
```

Anyone has an idea what am I missing here?

Btw, if you are wondering why the DateTime is displayed in GMT+1:00 zone, cause that's the timezone in which I want my DateTime objects to be by default.

Thanks!

Comment: Try comparing their millisecond values. Debugging will get you far.

Comment: Yeah comparing the millis returns that they are equal, but this should work as well - right?

Comment: What type is the value returned by `getCreationDate()`?

Comment: org.joda.time.DateTime

Comment: Can you please confirm that with a `println(response.getCreationDate.getClass())`? I don't see anything else wrong.

Comment: Yes, as I said it's jodatime DateTime. Here is the println:

    class org.joda.time.DateTime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code (example) :

```
    Chronology ch1 = GregorianChronology.getInstance();
    Chronology ch2 = ISOChronology.getInstance();

    DateTime dt = new DateTime("2013-12-31T22:59:21+01:00",ch1);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime("2013-12-31T22:59:21+01:00",ch2);

    System.out.println(dt);
    System.out.println(dt2);

    boolean b = dt.equals(dt2);

    System.out.println(b);
```

Will print :

```
2013-12-31T16:59:21.000-05:00
2013-12-31T16:59:21.000-05:00
false
```

You are probably comparing two [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)s with same date but different [Chronology](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Chronology.html.).

Answer (score 7):

`DateTime` inherits its `equals` method from `AbstractInstant`. It is implemented as such

```
public boolean equals(Object readableInstant) {
    // must be to fulfil ReadableInstant contract
    if (this == readableInstant) {
        return true;
    }
    if (readableInstant instanceof ReadableInstant == false) {
        return false;
    }
    ReadableInstant otherInstant = (ReadableInstant) readableInstant;
    return
        getMillis() == otherInstant.getMillis() &&
        FieldUtils.equals(getChronology(), otherInstant.getChronology());
}
```

Notice the last line comparing chronology. It's possible your instances' chronologies are different.

Comment: If I extract the chronology of the two datetime objects I get the following:

     `ISOChronology[+01:00]`
     `ISOChronology[Europe/Belgrade]`

But Belgrade IS in GMT+1:00.

Comment: @SpaseMarkovski There you go. Chronology is not equivalent to time zone.

Comment: Aren't they the same though? Europe/Belgrade IS IN GMT+1:00.

Comment: @SpaseMarkovski That's not the only purpose of a [Chronology](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Chronology.html).